# Appending bits produces the wrong result

Tags: java, append, operator-keyword, bit, bitwise-operators

When using bitwise operators and bit manipulation, I have an error writing the first bits as a zero.
Example:

```
000 o
0
001 e
1
0100 h
10100
0101 c
101000101
Should be:
000 o
000
001 e
000001
0100 h
0000010100
0101 c
00000101000101

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    data <<= 1;
    if (s.charAt(i)=='1')
        data |= 1;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The first couple of bits should be 0s however it's chopping them off until there's a 1.

Comment: Of course it is, there's no point in displaying leading zeroes

Comment: Is there anyway to keep them? Otherwise, I need to waste a bit at the beginning.

Comment: Not (without modification) in a single integer, there is no difference between 01 and 1 so the printing routine cannot know which one you meant. You could print all leading zeroes however, or store the intended length separately, or use an extra leading 1.